# Export excel file using exceljs to client

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'm trying to export excel file using exceljs library. I'm using AngularJS and NodeJS.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<a class="btn m-b-xs btn-info btn-doc" ng-click="exportExcel()" style='background-color: #34495e; margin-left: 5%;'>
</a>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.exportExcel = function() {
    $http.post('/api/exportExcel/exportExcel', {"data": $scope.data});
};
```

NodeJS:

```
const Excel = require('exceljs');

export async function exportExcel(req, res) {
    try {
    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('My Sheet');

    worksheet.columns = [
        { header: 'Id', key: 'id', width: 10 },
        { header: 'Name', key: 'name', width: 32 },
        { header: 'D.O.B.', key: 'DOB', width: 10 }
    ];
    worksheet.addRow({id: 1, name: 'John Doe', dob: new Date(1970,1,1)});
    worksheet.addRow({id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe', dob: new Date(1965,1,7)});

    var tempFilePath = tempfile('.xlsx');
    workbook.xlsx.writeFile(tempFilePath).then(function() {
        console.log('file is written');
        res.sendFile(tempFilePath, function(err){
            console.log('---------- error downloading file: ' + err);
        });
    });
} catch(err) {
    console.log('OOOOOOO this is the error: ' + err);
}
}
```

I've just found this example of code for generating excel just to try get excel file on client side and after that i will create my own file.
But for now i just get in log this error

```
file is written
(node:25624) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: res.sendFile is not a function
```

Does anyone can help me to get excel file in browser after i click on button for export?

**UPDATE**

controller:

```
$scope.exportExcel = function() {
            $http.post('/api/exportExcel/exportExcel', {"offer": $scope.offer})
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                var data = response.data,
                blob = new Blob([data], { type: response.headers('content-type') }),
                url = $window.URL || $window.webkitURL;
                $scope.fileUrl = url.createObjectURL(blob);
            });
        };
```

html:

```
<a class="btn m-b-xs btn-info btn-doc" ng-click="exportExcel()" ng-href="{{ fileUrl }}" download="table.xlsx">
<i class="fa"></i>Export</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

There were some problems, I have corrected them check and verify.

Definition of Route:-

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require("fs");
const Excel = require("exceljs");
var path = require("path");

router.get("/", async function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("---InSideFunction---");
  try {
    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet();

    worksheet.columns = [
      { header: "Id", key: "id", width: 10 },
      { header: "Name", key: "name", width: 32 },
      { header: "D.O.B.", key: "DOB", width: 10 }
    ];
    worksheet.addRow({ id: 1, name: "John Doe", DOB: new Date(1970, 1, 1) });
    worksheet.addRow({ id: 2, name: "Jane Doe", DOB: new Date(1965, 1, 7) });

    workbook.xlsx
      .writeFile("newSaveeee.xlsx")
      .then(response => {
        console.log("file is written");
        console.log(path.join(__dirname, "../newSaveeee.xlsx"));
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../newSaveeee.xlsx"));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("OOOOOOO this is the error: " + err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204906/discussion-on-answer-by-ankit-kumar-rajpoot-export-excel-file-using-exceljs-to-c).

Answer (score -1):

req and res are not associated with 'exceljs'.